# jQuery <input> watermark that stays when focused

Tags: jquery, watermark

I have some `<input>`s on my form, and I would like to watermark them with field labels. There are already myriad watermarking plugins, but best as I can tell they all clear the watermark when the `<input>` is focused, even if there's nothing entered.

What I'd like, ideally, is something that would **continue to display until the user typed something in**, focused or not.

Does anyone know of a plugin that does this already, or know of a code sample that might help guide my way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This plugin](http://fuelyourcoding.com/scripts/infield/) will retain the watermark when the input is focused, although it will hide on *any* keypress (even Ctrl).

Comment: I actaully ended up going with Paul Elliot's fork of that plugin, which requires a lot less CSS/HTML tomfoolery. http://github.com/paulelliott/In-Field-Labels-jQuery-Plugin. It's not perfect, but it's a great starting point.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a flexible plugin for this purpose. it gets to state: focused and filled and you can define your own css to manage the style such as visibility, color and ...
check the samples and full doc for [jQuery Placeholder here](http://www.tectual.com.au/posts/8/jQuery-Watermark-Plugin-Best-jQuery-Placeholder-.html)

Answer (score 0):

As another alternative, if you like one of the other plugins better for other reasons, it wouldn't be very difficult to alter the script so that watermark disappears on `keyup` rather than `focus`.